# How do I find the current directory, in Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-io

I want to know what the current directory is. I don't want to shell out to run `pwd`. Is there an easy way to do this in Dart?

Answer (score 45):

Indeed there is!

```dart
import 'dart:io';

main() {
  Directory current = Directory.current;
}
```

Note: this only works on the command-line, not in the browser.

Read more about the [API docs for Directory.current](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_io/Directory.html#current).

Comment: Nitpick: it's type of `Directory` not `String` :)

Comment: @Kei Sellgren same here :-)

Comment: `Directory.current.path` is the string.

Comment: please note that  `Directory.current.path` will change after using file picker. https://github.com/miguelpruivo/flutter_file_picker/issues/804

Answer (score 10):

`Directory.current.path` does it if you want a string, `Directory.current` for a Directory.

(note: `Directory` is defined in `dart:io`)

Comment: please note that Directory.current.path will change after using file picker. github.com/miguelpruivo/flutter_file_picker/issues/804